# UIManagedDocument Singleton Code openWithCompletionHandler called twice and crashes

Tags: ios, singleton, uimanageddocument

I am using Justin Driscoll's implementaion on [Core Data with a Single Shared UIManagedDocument](http://adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html).
Everything was fine in my iphone app until I moved it to a iPad storyboard and a splitview controller for the ipad app. The problem is openwithCompletionHandler is being called twice, once from my master view in viewDidLoad and again in my detail view viewWillLoad.  The calls are in quick succession and since the document is still in UIDocumentStateClosed when the second call is made to my performWithDocument method (below) of the singleton the app crashes.  I looked at e_x_p ' s answer for post [iOS5.1: synchronising tasks (wait for a completion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964571/ios5-1-synchronising-tasks-wait-for-a-completion) but @sychronized will not work in this case since performWithDocument below is called on the same thread.  How would I protect against multiple calls to openwithCompletionHandler?  The only way I can think to protect against this is to pause execution of one of the calls above until i am sure UIDocumentStateNormal is true and then release.  That though would freeze the main UI thread which is not good.  What though would be the best way todo this without freezing up the UI?

From the UIManagedDocumentSingleton code:

```
- (void)performWithDocument:(OnDocumentReady)onDocumentReady
{
    void (^OnDocumentDidLoad)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL success)
    {
        onDocumentReady(self.document);
    };

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.document.fileURL path]])
    {
        //This should never happen*******************
        [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL
                forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
               completionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];

    } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
    } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        OnDocumentDidLoad(YES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it as Justin suggested <strike>above</strike> below. Works fine in one of my apps for two years with ~20k users.

```
@interface SharedUIManagedDocument ()  
@property (nonatomic)BOOL preparingDocument; 
@end

- (void)performWithDocument:(OnDocumentReady)onDocumentReady
{
    void (^OnDocumentDidLoad)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL success) {
        onDocumentReady(self.document);
        self.preparingDocument = NO; // release in completion handler
    };

    if(!self.preparingDocument) {
        self.preparingDocument = YES; // "lock", so no one else enter here
        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.document.fileURL path]]) {
            [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
        } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
            [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
        } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
            OnDocumentDidLoad(YES);
        }
    } else {
        // try until document is ready (opened or created by some other call)
        [self performSelector:@selector(performWithDocument:) withObject:onDocumentReady afterDelay:0.5];
    }
}
```

**Swift** (not much tested)

```
typealias OnDocumentReady = (UIManagedDocument) ->()

class SharedManagedDocument {

private let document: UIManagedDocument
private var preparingDocument: Bool

static let sharedDocument = SharedManagedDocument()

init() {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as! NSURL
    let databaseURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(".database")
    document = UIManagedDocument(fileURL: databaseURL)
    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : true]
    document.persistentStoreOptions = options
    preparingDocument = false
}

func performWithDocument(onDocumentReady: OnDocumentReady) {

    let onDocumentDidLoad:(Bool) ->() = {
        success in
        onDocumentReady(self.document)
        self.preparingDocument = false
    }
    if !preparingDocument {
        preparingDocument = true
        if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(document.fileURL.path!) {
            println("Saving document for first time")
            document.saveToURL(document.fileURL, forSaveOperation: .ForCreating, completionHandler: onDocumentDidLoad)
        } else if document.documentState == .Closed {
            println("Document closed, opening...")
            document.openWithCompletionHandler(onDocumentDidLoad)
        } else if document.documentState == .Normal {
            println("Opening document...")
            onDocumentDidLoad(true)
        } else if document.documentState == .SavingError {
            println("Document saving error")
        } else if document.documentState == .EditingDisabled {
            println("Document editing disabled")
        }
    } else {
        // wait until document is ready (opened or created by some other call)
        println("Delaying...")
        delay(0.5, closure: {
            self.performWithDocument(onDocumentReady)
        })
    }
}

private func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
}
```

Comment: "// "lock", so no one else enter here" - It's a very big mistake

Comment: @adnako if you talking linguistics, i agree "lock" isn't a good word here as long as it's just a flag. But if you think this approach has weak sides please explain, i'm really interested!

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about multithreading. This code should work in single queue only. I use this pattern too and right now I'm trying to solve issue with calling [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad]; twice.

Comment: @adnako It's a singleton, implemented with GCD's dispatch_once (described in Effective Objective-C 2.0, for example). So we are guaranteed by iOS (you may argue, but it's not the issue here) here that instance is one and only with dispatch_once code. Which left us with one and only self.preparingDocument variable.

Comment: You do not understand. dispatch_once works only on static ivar creation. Anything else suffer of multithreading issues well. I shall send you a simple example later evening.

Comment: I can't quickly make example which crashes always. Run this project several times, it should crash after few starts. https://github.com/pomozoff/CoreDataExample

Comment: Thanks for taking time, but i have this code in production for half a year and thousands of sessions per day and it never crashed. This BOOL is for document creation/opening so whoever gets there first, "locks" the door and does the job.

Comment: [This code should work as needed](https://gist.github.com/pomozoff/1f691e29d6c0c2376c44)

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting and definitely a flaw in my code (sorry!). My first thought would be to add a serial queue as a property to your document handler class and perform the check on that.

```
self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.DocumentQueue", NULL);
```

and then in performWithDocument:

```
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath... // and so on
});
```

But that wouldn't work either...

You could set a BOOL flag when you call saveToURL and clear it in the callback. Then you can check for that flag and use performSelectorAfterDelay to call performWithDocument again a little later if the file is being created.

Answer (score 0):

The block of code that is shared between `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should be called only once. `numberOfRowsInSection` will always be called before the `tableView` tries to render the cells, so you should create an `NSArray` object that you can store the results of the fetch request into, and then use this array when rendering your cells:

```
@implementation FooTableViewController {
    NSArray *_privateArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [[UIManagedDocumentSingletonHandler sharedDocumentHandler] performWithDocument:^(FCUIManagedDocumentObject *document) {
        NSManagedObjectContext * context =  document.managedObjectContext;

        NSFetchRequest * request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"FCObject"];
        NSPredicate * searchStringPredicate = nil;
        if (searchFilterString)
        {
            searchStringPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word BEGINSWITH[c] %@",searchFilterString];
        }
        request.predicate = searchStringPredicate;
        request.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = YES;
        NSError * error;
        _privateArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        }];
    return _privateArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FCCell";
    FCardCell *cell = (FCCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    FCManagedObject * fcc = [_privateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.isWordVisible.on = fcc.isUsed;
    cell.fWord.text = fcc.word;
    return cell;
}
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head if you need to do something special with the `NSArray` to set it within the block (a la `__block`).

The major reason for this is that you need to make sure that 100% of the time the dataset used to determine the # of rows is the same size as when you are creating your cells. If they don't match then you will crash. Also since you don't have a block you don't need to dispatch to make `UITableViewCell` updates now.

Finally if `UIDocumentStateClosed` is causing problems you should either filter them out of your `NSFetch` results (additional predicate, see `NSCompoundPredicate` if required) or have code to handle them better in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I have consolidated the fetch request to a single initial call which cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection now use thus do not have the issue there anymore but the issue still exists.  I have updated the issue to simplify it.

Comment: could you `@synchronized (documentObject)` to sync on the object itself? Barring that is there a way you can delegate authority from master/detail so that only one of them needs to make the call (or if they have guaranteed execution order, you could pass a message between them (via `@protocol` likely) to execute on the second when the first is done.